# Cannot invoke "this.userService" is null when calling UserService.searchAll() in UserController

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, lombok

I’m currently developing a Spring Boot application and I’ve encountered a NullPointerException when trying to call the searchAll() method from UserService in my UserController. Here is the error message:

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Dec 14 16:27:51 JST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Cannot invoke "com.example.demo.service.UserService.searchAll()" because "this.userService" is null

`HTML Path:

src/main/resorces/templates/user/list.html

src/main/resorces/templates/index.html

```
`application.properties:

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:{myport}/{mydatabasename}?        useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Tokyo
spring.datasource.username={myusername}
spring.datasource.password={mypassword}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=false 
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false``
```

Here is the relevant code from my UserController:

```
`@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {
  /**
   * Service
   */
  private UserService userService;
  /**
   * 
   * @param model Model
   * @return 
   */
  @RequestMapping(value = "/user/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String displayList(Model model) {
    List<User> userlist = userService.searchAll();
    model.addAttribute("userlist", userlist);
    return "user/list";
  }
}`
```

`UserRepository:

```
`@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}`
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    /*
     * ID
     */

    @Id
    @Column(name ="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name ="name")
    private String name;


    @Column(name ="address")
    private String address;


    @Column(name ="phone")
    private String phone;


    @Column(name ="update_date")
    private String updateDate;


    @Column(name ="dalete_date")
    private String deleteDate;


}`
```

And here is my UserService:

```
 `@Service
 @RequiredArgsConstructor()
 public class UserService {

     private final UserRepository userRepository;

             public List<User> searchAll() {

         return userRepository.findAll();
         }
 }`
```

I’m using Lombok’s `@RequiredArgsConstructor` for dependency injection. I’ve checked that UserService and UserRepository are in the same package and that they are annotated with @Service and @Repository respectively. I’ve also confirmed that my Spring Boot version is above 2.3.

Despite these checks, I’m still facing the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using ` @RequiredArgsConstructor` but have no required arguments. Make the field `final`. Additionally the `@Repository` on the Spring Data repository doesn't add anything (but additional code), you can remove it.

Comment: I inadvertently forgot to add final to private UserService userService in UserController. Your advice was precise and very helpful. Thank you.